# Closest point to given point on $x$-axis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms

There are $n$ points on 2D plane and a point $X$ on $x$-axis. I need to find the point closest to $X$.  I can only think of brute force solution. Is there any way we could do this in logarithmic complexity.

Comment: It is irrelevant that $X$ happens to be on the x-axis.

Comment: Ok then, I would rephrase it by saying there is a set of points. I have a point X. I need to find the point in the set that is closest to X.

Comment: I can't imagine how you can do this without inspecting each point, so I doubt it can be done in better than linear time.

Comment: Whatif there are two sets of points, set A and set B. The points of setA are in 2D plane, and all the points in setB lie on x-axis. For all points in setB, find a point in setA which is closest to it.

Comment: Let there be N points in set A, and M points in set B. You can sort points in set B in $O(M \log M)$ time according to their $x$ components. (You can do this whenever the points are along a line, as you can rotate and translate the coordinate system to put the points on the $x$ axis.) You can then find the closest point in set B in logarithmic time, $O(\log M)$, using a binary search. That makes the overall time complexity $O\left((M+N)\log M\right)$, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you know nothing about the set of points, you can't help inspecting each point, so you won't get below $\Omega(n)$ in time complexity. If you have your points preprocessed in some way, then you'd do best to sort by $x$ coordinate. Then you can look for a point with nearest $x$ coordinate in $O(\log n)$. Suppose that point has coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$. You'd still have to increase your range to cover indices $j$ in the range $x-\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}\le x_j\le x+\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}$. So if your points are close to the $x$ axis, this still limits your search considerably. But if your points have small $x$ coordinates but large $y$ coordinates, you gain very little from this restriction. In the worst case, without further knowledge about the set of points you have, you are still at $O(n)$.